# Displaying only first child categories woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have code, which is displaying all sub categories. But I need to display only first-level, and on the second level display products

```
 1. Category
    1.1 First-level
       1.1.1 Second level
```

Code:

```
$second_level_cats = get_term_children($cat->term_id, $cat->taxonomy); 
foreach ($second_level_cats as $second_level_cat_id) :
    if(!get_term_children($cat_id, $cat->taxonomy)) :
        $second_level_cat = get_term($second_level_cat_id, $cat->taxonomy); 
    endif; 
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent cat using this code:

```
<?php
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$args=array(
            'parent' => $cat_id,
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
```